# iPhone - Showing Images from Server in Cover Flow

Tags: iphone, ios, coverflow

I want to display image using server link in Cover Flow can any one help me in this regards. I have successfully show the images in cover Flow which is present in my NSMainBundle. I have search many tutorial they are saying first you have to download the images than show them in your cover flow but i don't wana download the images

Answer (score 1):

The approach that you should use for this is to display a static image for each of the pages within the coverflow when it loads. At the same time you can load the images in the background and update each page when the associated image loads.

Personally, I quite like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for loading images in the background